# jQuery replaceWith() $this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide "show replies" when I click to show them. Problem is that when I click "show replies" all "show replies" buttons hides. I need to hide only that the one I click. This is the jQuery code:

```
         $(".replies_show").click (function(e){
            $(".replies_show").replaceWith(" ");
            $(this).next(".replies").show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".replies_show")` selects all elements having the class, therefore you are selecting all of them and then applying `replaceWith` to all of them again. However, `this` inside that call back function refers to the element that just clicked (i.e. the only clicked element not all of them).

Also, do not use `replaceWith` function just to hide an element, use `.hide()` instead.

So, replace

```
$(".replies_show").replaceWith(" ");
```

With

```
$(this).hide();
```

Comment: But then `$(this).next(".replies").show();` doesnt execute. Replies are not showing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to get the current element. Otherwise, you're selecting all the elements with the `.replies_show` class.

```js
$('.replies_show').on('click', function(e, el) {
  $(el).replaceWith(' '); // Does what you're looking for

  $(el).hide(); // Might be better, depending on what you're doing
  
  $(this).next('.replies').show();
  
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.hide()` function not `.replaceWith()`

```
$(".replies_show").click (function(e){
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next(".replies").show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need target only `clicked` item, so you need to use `$(this)` in callback function, something like below:

```
$(".replies_show").click (function(e){
    var $this = $(this);   // cache $(this)/clicked element

    $this.hide();          // clicked item will be hide (display: none) 
    $this.next(".replies") // next matched item of clicked item
        .show();           

    e.preventDefault();
});
```